Generics in Blazor component
I am writing a component that requries a generic parameter to be declared. I do not have my code in the page within a code block, but instead use a partial class.
All the examples I've found show that in the page it takes the form:
@typeparam TItem;

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public TItem ExampleList { get; set; }
....

how can I declare this using a class file? If I declare typeparam in the page and place my parameter declaration in the partial class, 'TItem' is not recognised. and I do not seem to be able to declare typeparam in the code behind.

All you need is to add the type param to the code-behind as well:
public partial class MyComponent<TItem>
{
  [Parameter]
  public TItem ExampleList { get; set; }
}

